# Can we use sessionFactory multiple times which provided by spring?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

but in my code i'm getting null pointer exception when i'm using session factory for second time . and it is working fine in first .

here is my code

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>
    <property name="password" value="root"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pdevice"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <array>
            <value>/LoginDTO.hbm.xml</value>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="loginDAO" class="com.raj.sprmvc.dao.LoginDAOImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="loginManager" class="com.raj.sprmvc.manager.LoginManagerImpl">
    <property name="loginDAO" ref="loginDAO"></property>
</bean>

<!-- <bean id="login" class="com.raj.sprmvc.controller.LoginController"> 
    <property name="loginManager" ref="loginManager"></property> </bean> -->


<bean id="commandController" name="/login.do" class="com.raj.sprmvc.controller.LoginController">
    <property name="loginManager" ref="loginManager"></property>
    <property name="commandClass" value="com.raj.sprmvc.dto.LoginDTO"></property>
    <property name="validator" ref="loginValidator"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="loginValidator" class="com.raj.sprmvc.validator.LoginValidator"></bean>


<!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++to update place+++++++++++++++++++++ -->




<bean id="updateUNDAO" class="com.raj.sprmvc.dao.UpdateUNDAOImpl">
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property> 
</bean>

<bean id="updateManager" class="com.raj.sprmvc.manager.UpdateManagerImpl">
    <property name="undao" ref="updateUNDAO"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="commandController1" name="/update.do"
    class="com.raj.sprmvc.controller.UpdateController">
    <property name="updateManager" ref="updateManager"></property>
    <property name="commandClass" value="com.raj.sprmvc.dto.LoginDTO"></property>
    <!-- <property name="validator" ref="loginValidator"></property> -->
</bean>
```

when i'm trying to use sessinfactory for second time it is giving nullpointer ..i know this basic concept but struggling to solve this pls share .......
thanks

this is the first module 
public class LoginDAOImpl implements LoginDAO{

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public boolean isExist(LoginDTO ldto) {

    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();

    Query query=session.createQuery(" FROM LoginDTO WHERE username='"+ldto.getUsername()+"'  AND  password='"+ldto.getPassword()+"'");


    if(query.uniqueResult()!=null){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}
```

}

and in second module

public class UpdateUNDAOImpl implements UpdateUNDAO{

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

public void update(LoginDTO ldto){

    Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
    System.out.println(session);
```

Transaction tr= session.beginTransaction();
        tr.begin();

```
    LoginDTO ldto1=(LoginDTO)session.load(LoginDTO.class, 1);
    ldto1.setPlace(ldto.getPlace());

    session.update(ldto1);


    tr.commit();
    session.close();
```

}
}

in this module the line Session session=sessionFactory.openSession(); is giving null pointer exception

exception
exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:659)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.27 logs.

exception

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by *second time*?

Comment: first i used sessionFactory.openSession() in my first module which is a simple login and here it is working fine .

Comment: But in my second module i want to update some data in database ,here i'm using same sessionFactory.openSession() but in another module .

Comment: Show us your relevant code and the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: In your xml uncomment 
    `<!-- <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property> -->` for UpdateUNDAO bean

Comment: i have uncommented  but still null pointer.